Kunen's Proof of Tukey's Lemma
In Foundations of Mathematics, Kunen proves Tukey's Lemma from the Well-Ordering Theorem (in Set Theory he proves it from Zorn's Lemma). I have a question about the notation he uses in Foundations of Mathematics.
$\textbf{Tukey's Lemma:}$ Let $\mathcal{F}\subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$ be of finite character and $X\in \mathcal{F}$. Then there exists a maximal $Y\in\mathcal{F}$ such that $X\subseteq Y$.
$\textbf{Original Construction:}$ During the proof the set $Y$ is recursively defined. Let $\kappa=|A|$ and $A=\{x_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa\}$ be a well-ordering of $A$ (which exists assuming Choice or Well-Ordering). Recursively define $Y_\beta\subseteq\{x_\xi:\xi<\beta\}$, for $\beta\leq\kappa$ by:
a. $Y_0 = X$
b. $Y_{\alpha+1}$ is $Y_\alpha\cup\{x_a\}$ if $Y_\alpha\cup\{x_a\}\in\mathcal{F}$; otherwise $Y_{\alpha+1}=Y_\alpha$.
c. $Y_\gamma = \bigcup\{Y_\alpha:\alpha<\gamma\}$ if $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal.
The rest of the proof follows by induction to show that $Y_\kappa$ is such a $Y$ we are looking for. The proof is simple to understand and reduces intuitively to adding elements of $A$ one by one until you cannot anymore.
My question is regarding the recursive definition of $Y_\beta$. Kunen specifically says that $Y_\beta\subseteq\{x_\xi:\xi<\beta\}$; that is, $Y_\beta$ is a subset of the first $\beta$ elements of $A$. Then $Y_0$ must be a subset of the first $0$ elements, i.e. empty. But $X=Y_0\subseteq\{x_\xi:\xi<0\}=\emptyset$ is a contradiction if $X$ is non-empty.
This construction is taken directly from the book, so either there is a mistake in the text or I am misinterpreting something.
$\textbf{Alternate Construction:}$ One correction could be to well order the remaining elements: $A\backslash X=\{x_\xi:\xi<\kappa'\}$. Then we can construct $Z_\beta\subseteq\{x_\xi:\xi<\beta\}$ and ultimately $Z=Z_{\kappa'}$ to be the remaining elements of $A$ such that $Y=X\cup Z$ is maximal:
a. $Z_0=\emptyset$
b. $Z_{\alpha+1}$ is $Z_\alpha\cup\{x_\alpha\}$ if $X\cup Z_\alpha\cup\{x_\alpha\}\in\mathcal{F}$; otherwise $Z_{\alpha+1}=Z_\alpha$
c. $Z_\gamma = \bigcup\{Z_\alpha:\alpha<\gamma\}$ if $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal.
This way $Z_\beta\subseteq\{x_\xi:\xi<\beta\}$ is satisfied. Is there a mistake in the original proof? Or did I make a mistake?

What is the "mistake"? Does anything go wrong if you just assume he must have meant $Y_\beta\subseteq {x_\xi: \xi < \beta}\cup X$?

Yes that would be a correct and valid proof. I was just wondering why that was not included or corrected, I looked at multiple editions of the text. If it was an error it was not corrected.
